# Join large table having indexes with small table

Tags: mysql, join

I have large table called event in MySql Database having 10 million records.

**Event**

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
    `eventId` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `eventTime` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 1431201865000 (epoch is milliseconds)',
    `sourceId` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: pole-code: 1 = JA005, patrolCarCode: 5000 = D4588',
    PRIMARY KEY (`eventId`),
    INDEX `eventTime` (`eventTime`),
    INDEX `sourceId` (`sourceId`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=12343262;
```

I have small table having around 70 records.

**Source**

```
CREATE TABLE `source` (
    `sourceId` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `sourceName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: pole-code: JA005, patrolCarCode:D4588' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `sourceGps` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Only for Fixed source (Poles) ex: 25.110227 N  55.239798 E, 24.993183 N  55.250382 E, 0.000000 N  0.000000 E' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `sourceAddress` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Only for Fixed source (Poles) ex: Dubai, Bur Dubai, Burjman Center Interchange' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `sourceAltAddress` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Alternative address, ex: address in arabic' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`sourceId`),
    INDEX `sourceName` (`sourceName`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=71
;
```

**Data**

```
INSERT INTO `event` (`eventId`, `eventTime`, `sourceId`) VALUES
    ( 1474261476616, 33, 1),
    ( 1474261438966, 26, 2),
    ( 1474261479346, 25, 3),
    ( 1474261429952, 8, 5),
    ( 1474261477316, 33, 6)

INSERT INTO `source` (`sourceId`, `sourceName`, `sourceGps`, `sourceAddress`) VALUES
    ( 1, 'JA001', '25.110227 N  55.239798 E', 'Interchange'),
    ( 2, 'JA002', '25.110227 N  55.239798 E', 'Interchange'),
    ( 3, 'JA003', '25.110227 N  55.239798 E', 'Interchange'),
    ( 4, 'JA004', '25.110227 N  55.239798 E', 'Interchange'),
    ( 5, 'JA005', '25.110227 N  55.239798 E', 'Interchange')
```

**Task**

I want to get all event which happened after specific time say '1474261429952'.

After searching I have formulated below query so far, which brings result but speed is very slow. 
It takes almost 1.5 minutes to retrieve results from table.

```
SELECT count(source.sourceId) as 'totalEvents', source.sourceId, source.sourceGps, 
source.sourceAddress  from event  inner join source on event.sourceId = source.sourceId  
where eventTime >= 1474261429952 group by source.sourceId
```

**Explain Result:**

[Here is explain result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uItc.png)

Please guide me how I can speed it up.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your query to see where its slowing down?

Comment: Pls include the result of the `explain` in your question.

Comment: counting Event.EventTime or event.sourceID seems like it would be able to use the index on event which I would think would run faster. but an explain on the query would make it easier.

Comment: But most likely you need a multi column index in your `event` table on `sourceid, eventtime` fields.

Comment: Please find explain result here. http://imgur.com/a/1AJb9

Comment: @Shadow.. eventtime and sourceid both are indexed. please see table structure.

Comment: I did not say these columns were not indexed. I said you needed a multi-column index. A single index that spans over multiple columns. MySQL can use 1 index per table in a query. Pls copy the results of the explain into the question as text. I cannot access the image version.

Comment: @Shadow.. Please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a multi-column index to `events` table covering the fields `sourceid, eventtime` (in this particular order).

Reason: MySQL can use one index per table in a query (well, index merges are a small exception). You have separate indexes on the `sourceid, eventtime` fields, which MySQL does consider for use, but dismisses them (see possible keys and key fields in the explain result) - probably alone neither is selective enough.

Check index usage after the index is created through another `explain`. You may have to use index hints (`use index` or `force index`) to make MySQL use the new indexes, although an `analyse table` may also help with that.

Comment: I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Although Shadow points out the issue of multiple field index vs individual, I would recommend the different order of (eventtime, sourceid) instead of (sourceid, eventtime).  Reason being...  if your data is 10 years old, you still have to go through every source from however old to current.  Instead of just jumping to the current date range in question.  Also, instead of grouping by your SOURCE table instead of the EVENT, you are taking advantage of the event's index since they keys are the same from the join anyhow.

Since the source is

```
SELECT 
      count(*) as 'totalEvents', 
      source.sourceId, 
      source.sourceGps, 
      source.sourceAddress  
   from 
      event  
         inner join source 
            on event.sourceId = source.sourceId
   where 
      eventTime >= 1474261429952 
   group by 
      event.sourceId
```

If you DO want to try having the index based on ( SourceID, EventTime ), I would alter the query and put the SOURCE table in the first position and write as...  It would be interesting the time performance differences you get back.

```
SELECT 
      S.sourceId, 
      S.sourceGps, 
      S.sourceAddress,
      count(*) as totalEvents
   from 
      source S
         join event E
            on S.sourceId = E.sourceId
           AND E.eventTime >= 1474261429952
   group by 
      S.sourceId
```

Comment: It did not make much difference. It saved only 5 seconds.